# Setting the RowDefinition Height from StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF style I have defined a standard grid row height I'd like to apply to several places like so:

```
<system:Double x:Key="TableRowHeight">22</system:Double>
```

However it does not work when I'd like to apply this like so:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource TableRowHeight}"/>
```

Instead I need to create a complete style like:

```
<Style x:Key="GridTableRow" TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
    <!--<Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource TableRowHeight}"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
</Style>
```

As can be seen from the commented out line trying to reference the numeric constant within the Style definition does not work either, but the "hardcoded" value does.

Now I've looked it up and I guess it is because the type associated with the Height property is GridLength and it somehow does not manage to automatically cast the double value when comming from another resource...

The problem is that there does not seem to be a way of creating a GridLength object from XAML. The Value propery is readonly. So something like this does not work either:

```
<Style x:Key="GridTableRow" TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}">
    <Setter Property="Height">
        <Setter.Value>
            <GridLength Value="{StaticResource TableRowHeight}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is there a way to get this to work, or should I just forget using that constant and just use the RowDefinition style with the hardcoded value in place of the constant?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you "hard code" values, the XAML processor looks up a converter that can convert it from string to the necessary type. Even your `TableRowHeight` resource is using [DoubleConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doubleconverter.aspx) to be created. `GridLength` uses [GridLengthConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlengthconverter.aspx).

So there is no automatic cast / conversion happening in the compiler -- WPF needs to explicitly look up a class and call a convert method. In the case of `StaticResource`, it skips this step.

Bindings do use type converters though, so the following *would* work as you expect:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource TableRowHeight}}" />
```

This works because `GridLengthConverter` knows how to convert from `Double`. In your case, this should not be necessary, though. If you initialize a `GridLength` resource in the same way you initialized `Double` (inside the tags), the string conversion will be called before the resource is assigned:

```
<GridLength x:Key="TableRowHeight">22</GridLength>
```

Then you would be able to call the resource directly.

Comment: The suggestion with using the `{Binding Source=...}` syntax works! Thanks!

Comment: Defining the GridLength as suggested above and in other responses works as well, but has the same drawback as having to define the entire RowDefinition style with a hardcoded value... You cannot link the value to the system:double resource. (At least I haven't found a way to refer to another resource from the inside of the tag...) And there is no "Value" attribute exposed on the GridLength...

Comment: EDIT: The reason I'm insisting on linking to the double value, as I may need to reuse that value in some other context, that does not take a GridLength or other specialized resource...

Comment: @bjavor Well, if you want a GridLength resource that links to the Double resource, I think you've reached the limits of what can be written in XAML. You could always add resources in C#, like `Resources.Add("GridLength", new GridLength((double)FindResource("Double")))`, but this seems to be getting more complicated than it needs to be...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:t="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <Window.Resources>
        <t:GridLength x:Key="gridHeight">50</t:GridLength>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="{StaticResource gridHeight}"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     ....
```

Answer (score 2):

you will have to create the resource of type `GridLength` in order to apply  as `RowDefinition.Height` is of type `GridLength`:

```
<window:GridLength x:Key="TableRowHeight">50</window:GridLength>
```

This will work in anyway you want to apply it.