# Namespace for creating StaticResource of GridLength

Tags: wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces, staticresource, gridlength

I'm trying to create a StaticResource of the type GridLength to use in my XAML. I want to define columns of uniform width, but I cannot seem to find the Namespace in Xaml that allows me to define my StaticResource. In the documentation, I have found the the GridLength struct exists under this namespace *Windows.UI.Xaml*; however, I cannot seem to find it when I try to include the name space at the top of my Xaml file.

Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl ...
        xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows.UI.Xaml;" >

     <UserControl.Resources>
        <windows:GridLength property="doubleLength" x:Key="MyColumnWidth">50</windows:GridLength>
     </UserControl.Resources>
     ...

     <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource MyColumnWidth}"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource MyColumnWidth}"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="{StaticResource MyColumnWidth}"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       ....        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here are my questions:
1. What namespace do I use?
2. How do I declare a GridLength StaticResource? 
3. Am I using the property attribute correctly? I found it in the documentation but am not sure how to use it appropriately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify width/height as resource in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279732/specify-width-height-as-resource-in-wpf)

Comment: This one explains how to define GridLength resource:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18637378/1023619

Comment: You don't need any namespace. Just `<GridLength x:Key="MyColumnWidth">50</GridLength>` What's `property="doubleLength"` all about?

Comment: Ed you solved my problem! Write this as an answer and I'll mark this as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any namespace, because `Windows.UI.Xaml` is the default. Just this:

```
<GridLength x:Key="MyColumnWidth">50</GridLength>
```

Will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

As Ed pointed out, I do not need to use a name space to declare a StaticResource of GridLength. All I had to do was type:`<GridLength x:Key="MyColumnWidth">50</GridLength>`